# Django Simple Captcha Can't get ValidationError exception

Tags: django, django-forms, captcha

How to get it?

In [this](https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) tutorial, it says that `if the user didn’t provide a valid response to the CAPTCHA challenge, the form will raise a ValidationError:`

**my form**

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    captcha = CaptchaField(label=_("Captcha"))
```

**my view**

```
try:
    form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        pass
except Exception, ex:
    LOG.debug("Captcha Error: %s" % str(ex))
```

I couldn't get any exception from the form. How to accomplish it? Any ideas?

***UPDATE1***

I put some `subprocess.call(["logger", "-t", "blah", "blahblah"])` statement in the source code of captcha, in 'clean' function but it seems that it doesn't even enter the `clean`. And also it is the only place where ValidationError is raised.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling `is_valid()` on the form and unless you do it no validation error will be raised.

I guess you want something like:

```
try:
    form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        #Do something
except Exception, ex:
    #ValidationErrror will be caught here
    LOG.debug("Captcha Error: %s" % str(ex))
```

But still you will not get any exception. Reason: When you call `is_valid`, django internally uses a method named `full_clean`. If any of the fields raise a ValidationError, internally this method catches it and updates an attribute named `errors` on the form. So, your view will never get any `ValidationError` raised by form field.

The way to know if a `ValidationError` is raised is to access the `errors` attribute of the form.

So, code for that would be

```
form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    pass
#In case of valid form next line will not be called because form.errors will be an empty dict
if form.errors and 'captcha' in form.errors:
    LOG.debug("Captcha Error:")  
    #also you can access exact error by form.errors['captcha']
```

Comment: I tried those, but couldn't get it work. I also used forms.ValidationError, but again not working.

Comment: are you calling `is_valid()`?

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that. I updated it again ;) Sorry for that.

Comment: I updated my answer, please check. Sorry for not noticing the bug first time.

Comment: Ok the funny thing here is that the errors come empty. I use 0.2.0 version of this package because this the only one out there who has an rpm for CentOS. I tried to create one for CentOS from 0.3.6 Fedora source package but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `forms.ValidationError`

[Have a look at the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/)

Comment: I tried it but no luck. Also, doesn't `Exception` itself mean all exceptions that might be raised?

Comment: Actually, my view consists of only the code I posted + `if  request.POST ` conditional block.s That's all ;)